# Why can't I get my discord bot to add users to a role?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I've been looking for the answer everywhere but nothing appears to work. Maybe someone here could help me?

"!imprison1 @user spam" should result in the bot sending a message "User has been imprisoned for spam" and adding a role called "Prisoner" to the mentioned user.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready!');
});

function getUserFromMention(mention) {
  if (!mention) return;

  if (mention.startsWith('<@') && mention.endsWith('>')) {
    mention = mention.slice(2, -1);

    if (mention.startsWith('!')) {
      mention = mention.slice(1);
    }

    return client.users.cache.get(mention);
  }
}

function getUserFromMentionRegEx(mention) {
  const matches = mention.match(/^<@!?(\d+)>$/);
  const id = matches[1];

  return client.users.cache.get(id);
}

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;

  const withoutPrefix = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length);
  const split = withoutPrefix.split(/ +/);
  const command = split[0];
  const args = split.slice(1);

  if (command === 'imprison1') {
    if (args[0]) {
      let user = getUserFromMention(args[0]);

      if (!user) {
        return message.reply('Invalid user.');
      }

      return message.channel.send(
        `${user.username} has been imprisoned for ${args[1]}`
      );
      user.roles.add('749291623170572428');
    }

    return message.channel.send(`Add @mention to imprison a user.`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Try `user.roles.add('<@&749291623170572428>');` instead?

Comment: @Acc-lab I tried your method, but still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your function, `getUserFromMention` returns a `User` object, not a `GuildMember` object.

Change:

```js
return client.users.cache.get(mention);
```

With:

```js
// Remember to pass the message as the second parameter, as the message is undefined currently.
return message.guild.members.cache.get(mention);
```

---

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

const config = require("./config.json");

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} is ready.`);
});

client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;
    if (!message.guild) return false;
    if (message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return false;

    const arguments = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).split(/ +/g);
    const commandName = arguments.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (commandName == "imprison1") {
        if (!arguments[0]) return message.channel.send("Add @mention to imprison a user.");
        if (!arguments[1]) return message.channel.send("Please provide a reason.");

        const user = message.guild.members.cache.get(getUserFromMention(arguments[0])) || message.guild.members.cache.get(arguments[0]);
        const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("749291623170572428");
        if (!user) return message.channel.send("Invalid user.");
        if (!role) return message.channel.send("Invalid role.");

        user.roles.add(role).then(role => {
            message.channel.send(`${user.user.tag} has been imprisoned for ${arguments.slice(2, 2000).join(" ")}`);
        }).catch(error => message.channel.send(`Couldn't add the role. | ${error}`));
    };
});

function getUserFromMention(mention) {
    if (!mention) return false;

    const Matches = mention.match(/^<@!?(\d+)>$/);

    return Matches ? Matches[1] : false;
};

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

Comment: If this is what you meant, it's not working either. Message remains undefined and I get

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined"

`function getUserFromMention(mention, message) {
  if (!mention) return;

  if (mention.startsWith('<@') && mention.endsWith('>')) {
    mention = mention.slice(2, -1);

    if (mention.startsWith('!')) {
      mention = mention.slice(1);
    }

    return message.guild.members.cache.get(mention);
  }
}`

Comment: Call the function like this: `getUserFromMention(args[0], message);`.

Comment: This returns "undefined has been imprisoned for undefined"

Comment: @AK I rewrote the entire code for you. Tell me if you have the same issue.